# Confused about ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

What i am trying to do is to remove table row after completing ajax request.
html page is generated from php script.
Code example:

```
    echo "<script>";
                            echo "var trid = 'removetr$ChildSubnetID';";
                            echo "function funcBefore(){\$('#removetr$ChildSubnetID').remove();\$('#loadimg').show();}";
                            echo "function funcResults(data){\$(\"#message\").html(data);$(\"#loadimg\").hide();}";
                            echo "\$(document).ready(function(){
                                \$(\"#gotoa$ChildSubnetID\").bind(\"click\",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID=\"$ChildSubnetID\";
                                    var SubnetDEL=\"$ChildSubnet\";
                                    \$.ajax({
                                        url: \"exec.php\",
                                        type:\"POST\",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:\"HTML\",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });";
                            echo "</script>";
                            echo "<tr id='removetr".$ChildSubnetID."'><td>$ChildSubnetID</td><td>$ChildSubnet</td><td><center><p id='gotoa".$ChildSubnetID."' onclick='return confirm(\"Удалить подсеть $ChildSubnet?\")' style='cursor:pointer;
    other style...'>Удалить $ChildSubnet</p></center></td></tr>";
```

The result is a table with 3 columns.
When i go to to "view page source" i get the following code from browser:

```
<script>var trid = 'removetr4';
function funcBefore(){$('#removetr4').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}
function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}
$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa4").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="4";
                                    var SubnetDEL="1.1.1.1/29";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr4'><td id='removetr4'>4</td><td id='removetr4'>1.1.1.1/29</td><td id='removetr4'><center><p id='gotoa4' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 1.1.1.1/29?")' style='cursor:pointer;
other style attributes...'>Удалить 1.1.1.1/29</p></center></td></tr>
```

But every time when i press to

element, i get my show-hide image, but  row doesnt disappear.
I can see in page source

```
function funcBefore(){$('#removetr4').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}
```

Where i can see that element name(#removetr4) presents
And also i see html code

```
<tr id='removetr4'>
```

So here i see that row id also is corrent.
Can someone tell what is wrong with code? Why tr rows doesnt disappearing after ajax call?

One update. If in put in script part manual identificator-row disappears when i do click event.

For example from this

```
echo "function funcBefore(){\$('#removetr".$ChildSubnetID."').remove();\$('#loadimg').show();}";
```

to this

```
echo "function funcBefore(){\$('#removetr4').remove();\$('#loadimg').show();}";
```

Full HTML code:

```
<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='../keagpontyle2.css'><script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script></head>
<body><center><div id='loadimg' style='display:none;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100%;opacity: 0.9;background:black';font: 35px Courier New;color: white;><center><img src='Curve-Loading.gif' style='position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;></img><center><font color='red' size='5' face='Courier New'>Загрузка</font></center></center></div></center>
<center><table id='topMenu'><tr><th id='header' colspan='4'><center>Kea GPon UI</center><div id='infomessage'>Logged in as administrator</div></th></tr><tr><td><a href='../'>Главная</a></td><td><a href='../sites'>Конфигурация сайтов</a></td><td><div id='activemenu'>Конфигурация подсетей</div></td><td><a href='../leases'>Операции с адресами</a></td></tr></table></div></div><table id='sitecreate'><tr><td id='topMenuSite' colspan='4'>Создание и удаление подсетей</td></tr></table><table id='sitecreate'><tr><td colspan='2' id='topMenuSite3'>Операции с существующими сетями</td><td colspan='3' id='topMenuSite3'>Добавление новых подсетей</td></tr><tr><td><form action='' method='post'><select name='Sites' id='selects2'><option value='0'>Выберите Сайт</option><option value='CTA2-OLT1-MGM'>CTA2-OLT1-MGM</option></select></td><td><input type='submit' name='ShowSubnets' value='Показать подсети' / id='SiteAddButton'></form></td><td><form action='' method='post'><select name='SitesToAddSubnets' id='selects2'><option value='0'>Выберите Сайт</option><option value='CTA2-OLT1-MGM'>CTA2-OLT1-MGM</option></select></td><td><input type='text' name='NewSubnet' placeholder='Сеть/Префикс' id='selectstext'></td><td><input type='submit' name='AddSubnet' value='Добавить' / id='SiteAddButton'></form></td></tr></table><div id='message'><li>Вы выбрали 'CTA2-OLT1-MGM'</li></div></br><table id='currentsites'><tr><th>ID подсети</th><th>Подсеть</th><th>Действие</th></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr4';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr4').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa4").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="4";
                                    var SubnetDEL="1.1.1.1/29";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr4'><td id='removetr4'>4</td><td id='removetr4'>1.1.1.1/29</td><td id='removetr4'><center><p id='gotoa4' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 1.1.1.1/29?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 1.1.1.1/29</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr5';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr5').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa5").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="5";
                                    var SubnetDEL="5.5.5.0/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr5'><td id='removetr5'>5</td><td id='removetr5'>5.5.5.0/24</td><td id='removetr5'><center><p id='gotoa5' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 5.5.5.0/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 5.5.5.0/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr6';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr6').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa6").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="6";
                                    var SubnetDEL="2.2.2.2/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr6'><td id='removetr6'>6</td><td id='removetr6'>2.2.2.2/24</td><td id='removetr6'><center><p id='gotoa6' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 2.2.2.2/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 2.2.2.2/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr7';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr7').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa7").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="7";
                                    var SubnetDEL="7.7.7.7/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr7'><td id='removetr7'>7</td><td id='removetr7'>7.7.7.7/24</td><td id='removetr7'><center><p id='gotoa7' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 7.7.7.7/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 7.7.7.7/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr8';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr8').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa8").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="8";
                                    var SubnetDEL="8.8.8.8/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr8'><td id='removetr8'>8</td><td id='removetr8'>8.8.8.8/24</td><td id='removetr8'><center><p id='gotoa8' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 8.8.8.8/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 8.8.8.8/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr9';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr9').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa9").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="9";
                                    var SubnetDEL="9.9.9.9/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr9'><td id='removetr9'>9</td><td id='removetr9'>9.9.9.9/24</td><td id='removetr9'><center><p id='gotoa9' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 9.9.9.9/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 9.9.9.9/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr10';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr10').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa10").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="10";
                                    var SubnetDEL="10.10.10.10/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr10'><td id='removetr10'>10</td><td id='removetr10'>10.10.10.10/24</td><td id='removetr10'><center><p id='gotoa10' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 10.10.10.10/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 10.10.10.10/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr11';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr11').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa11").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="11";
                                    var SubnetDEL="11.11.11.11/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr11'><td id='removetr11'>11</td><td id='removetr11'>11.11.11.11/24</td><td id='removetr11'><center><p id='gotoa11' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 11.11.11.11/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 11.11.11.11/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr12';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr12').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa12").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="12";
                                    var SubnetDEL="12.12.12.12/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr12'><td id='removetr12'>12</td><td id='removetr12'>12.12.12.12/24</td><td id='removetr12'><center><p id='gotoa12' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 12.12.12.12/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 12.12.12.12/24</p></center></td></tr><script>var trid = 'removetr13';function funcBefore(){$('#removetr13').remove();$('#loadimg').show();}function funcResults(data){$("#message").html(data);$("#loadimg").hide();}$(document).ready(function(){
                                $("#gotoa13").bind("click",function(){
                                    var Operation='DelSubnet';
                                    var DelID="13";
                                    var SubnetDEL="13.13.13.13/24";
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "exec.php",
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data:({operation:Operation,delid:DelID,subnet:SubnetDEL}),
                                        dataType:"HTML",
                                        beforeSend:funcBefore,
                                        success:funcResults
                                    });
                                });
                            });</script><tr id='removetr13'><td id='removetr13'>13</td><td id='removetr13'>13.13.13.13/24</td><td id='removetr13'><center><p id='gotoa13' onclick='return confirm("Удалить подсеть 13.13.13.13/24?")' style='cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #1080b0;
    width:60%;
    align:center;
    font: 15px Courier New;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #1080b0;'>Удалить 13.13.13.13/24</p></center></td></tr></table></center></body></html>
```

Comment: The code shown has *multiple elements* with the `id` "removetr4".  `id` values need to be unique.

Comment: No, this is a part.
Each tr have uniq id

Comment: You can claim that you're not re-using `id` values all you like, but *in the code shown* you very clearly are.  Do a "find" operation on this very page and look for the string: `id='removetr4'`  Observe that it is being used in multiple elements in your HTML.  Re-using the same `id` is invalid HTML, which leads to undefined JavaScript behavior.

Comment: No. This is a part of code and page source.
Rows are generated in the loop.
Other id's of rows are uniqe also are function funcBefore
I can see in page source 
<tr id='removetr5'>
<tr id='removetr6'>...
And so on

Comment: Instead of arguing that the code you're showing us isn't actually the code you're showing us, please take some time to create a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.  The problem you're describing is functionality in the HTML/JavaScript, so you can remove the PHP parts and demonstrate just the relevant HTML and just the relevant JavaScript (both of which you can find in the page source in your browser), creating a clickable example which demonstrates the code not working as expected.

Comment: Ok, i posted full html code

Answer (score 0):

I found what is wrong.
The unique id for tr is not the only thing that must be unique. In the code function names are the same:)
So before each `<tr>` function name "funcResults" must also be unique.